# Struts 2 checkbox : What's the use of the value attribute when the fieldValue can only be true or false?

Tags: java, checkbox, struts2, struts

- Why do we need a **value** attribute as well as a **fieldValue** attribute in `s:checkbox` tag, unlike `s:textfield`, which has only the **value** attribute ?
- Does the `s:checkbox` tag's `fieldValue` attribute allow strings other than "**true**" or "**false**" ?
  In Struts2 in Action (Manning) , it says about the `fieldValue` attribute

> The actual value that’ll be submitted by the checkbox. Maybe true or
>   false

That is, if I use

`<s:checkbox name="wantMoreChocolates" fieldValue="true"/>`

then **wantMoreChocolate** can only be Boolean type in the java class. In that case, **why do the docs specify the type of fieldValue to be a String and not Boolean** ?

- Moreover, about the value property, it says

> the value attribute, as with the other UI components, points to the
>   actual Java-side property to which the component is bound, a Boolean
>   in this case.

If through "**value**" we specify the actual property to which the component is bound, **then what's the role of the name attribute**. Since, the name attribute has to point to a Boolean value, why does it have to use the value attribute to bind it to another boolean ?

- Why can't prepopulation occur solely on the basis of the property corresponding to the name attribute

Comment: Can you consider accepting my answer?

Answer (score 9):

I think I can have a word about this because I have struggled a lot with this topic.

What we can find in [official documentation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/checkbox.html) about `fieldValue` of `<s:checkbox>` says:

> ```
> Name           fieldValue
> Required       FALSE
> Default        TRUE
> Evaluated      FALSE
> Description    The actual HTML value attribute of the checkbox.
> ```

But it's saying nothing. I suggest to change it to:

> With `fieldValue`, we can submit a `String` type value into action
>   class.

It means:

- When the string literally is `"true"` or `"false"`, and the variable in action class is of `boolean` type, the string is parsed automatically into boolean value to be stored in the `boolean` type variable.
- If we do not define `fieldValue` at all,  the default value `"true"` of string type is always submitted to the variable, if there is any defined in Action class to hold it.

Note that **if we have `fieldValue` set, but the checkbox is not checked, nothing will be sent to backend, meaning the `String` type field to receive the checkbox's value will be `null`.**

But, it can do more than that. Let's see a real-world example combining `<s:checkbox />` and Struts 2 Action class fields' naming rules.

Imagine I have a list of checkbox, for example, for a list of Users to select, and each checkbox contains its `idUser` to process. Now if I want to parse more than one `idUser` to do my task, I can define:

```
<s:iterator value="listUsers">
    <s:checkbox name="userId" id="userId" fieldValue="%{idUser}"
    ....
</s:iterator>
```

Now we will receive a list of numbers in my action class, but with same `name`. Then we define a field of type `List<String>` or an array to receive all these IDs of users:

```
private List<String> userId;
```

with its getter/setter. Then we can do what we want with this list. **Remember that if we want to do calculations with them, these numbers must be parsed into Integer/Long/Whatever you like.**

Moreover, if we want to submit "YES/NO" or "1/0", or "radiant/dire" in a checkbox(you name it, and now you know what game I play), we can put a simple JavaScript function in the `onchange` event of this checkbox to monitor its status, or, more simply, parse its value in action class.

If we have:

```
<s:checkbox id="myCamp" name="myCamp" fieldValue="radiant"></s:checkbox>
```

And in action class we must have:

```
String myCampString = null;
if (StringUtils.isBlank(myCamp)){  //myCamp = null, means I am in Dire.
    myCampString = "dire";
} else if (myCamp.equalsIgnoreCase("radiant")){ //myCamp = "radiant", means I am in Radiant.
    myCampString = "radiant";
}
// then we process myCampString, now it cannot be null.
```

***************************I am the middle river*******************************

As for `value="true"/"false"`, I think it's a good example where we programmers cannot name things properly and think everyone can understand what we are talking about :). It can have some clearer name like `preselected`/`selectByDefault`, etc.

Again, refrencing Struts 2 DOC, we have:

> ```
> Name         value
> Required     FALSE
> Default  
> Evaluated    FALSE
> Type         String
> Description  Preset the value of input element.
> ```

Actually, it would be better if we put:

> `value` in `<s:checkbox>` define whether this checkbox should be checked when it is rendered for the first time. (*)

(*) Note that if `value` changes after it finished loading the page, Struts 2 will not populate the value into `<s:checkbox />` to change its status. JavaScript functions are responsible for this part, for example AngularJS.

For example, if I want to create a new `User` with a form, and by default every user is `active` when it's created, we can put this:

```
    <s:checkbox name="isActive" id="isActive" value="true"></s:checkbox>
```

But, when in a form of editing users, we want to make it checked when the user is active, and not to be checked when is not active, we can do this:

```
<s:checkbox name="isActive" id="isActive" value="%{user.isActive}"
```

So that's some tips to make it more understandable, although the DOC has made it clear (in the author's way, I think).

Answer (score 2):

in short `fieldValue` is The actual HTML value attribute of the checkbox and that will be submitted by the check box.Generally we need not to set this value since this is true by default.

On the other hand `value` parameter will be used to Preset the value of input element.Please go through the Struts2 form tag document to understand how exactly its working

- [struts-2-form-tags](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/form-tags.html)
- [struts-2-checkbox-tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/checkbox-tag.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look up the "key" attribute of checkbox. That may be all that you need. If you don't want to use the "key" attribute, read on.

I have found better luck using "value" attribute. I am a bit confused about "fieldValue" myself. I have seen that "fieldValue" can be used for showing the current value, but if you don't have the "value" attribute, the value (after changing on the form) is not sent to the action method.

Answer (score 0):

`fieldValue` is the value attribute of checkbox that will be submitted by the check box.
`fieldValue` can be `String`, `boolean` (true/false) etc depending upon your requirement.
 For more info have a glance at this link http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-scheckbox-checkbox-example/